# Hello I was confused about this code because purely from a technical stand point it should work

Tags: python

This is supposed to take three int values, and give you the LOWEST amount

```
num1 = int(input())
num2 = int(input())
num3 = int(input())

if (num1 < num2) and (num1 < num3):
    print(num1)
elif num2 < num3
     print(num2)
else:
    print(num3)
```

I know it's messy and kinda hard to read but my point is when i put something like 7 15 3, it always outputs 15. Why?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.

Comment: Your posted code fails to run due to a syntax error.  "Kinda hard to read" means that you're not yet ready for others to help you.  Your posted code hangs waiting for input -- don't expect us to enter test data, or to build a test file.

Comment: Just elemental logic. Try 20, 1, 2

Comment: Other than the missing colon on the elif line, it works for me? I input 7, 15, 3 and it spits out 3.

Comment: In spite of the missing `:` on second if, the logic is right. You must be confusing execution values. For testing, replace the `int(input())` with 7, 15 and 3. And fix the syntax.

Comment: Did you want `if (num1 < num2) and (num2 < num3):`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing a colon after the elif.  The code gives the expected answer:

```
num1 = int(input("Enter: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter: "))
num3 = int(input("Enter: "))

if (num1 < num2) and (num1 < num3):
    print(num1)
elif num2 < num3:
     print(num2)
else:
    print(num3)
```

Answer (score 2):

I reprodcued papke's result: adding a colon to the end of the `elif` line fixed the syntax error and produced the output you expected.

Taking advantage of the built-in `min` function, you could refactor your code along these lines:

```
num1 = int(input())
num2 = int(input())
num3 = int(input())

print(min([num1, num2, num3]))
```